# Non-offensive equivalent to KISS

Tags: slang, colloquialisms, popular-refrains

Is there a non-offensive way to tell someone:

> is better to (k)eep (i)t (s)imple, (s)...

**Update**

Let's say someone came with his part of the homework done, then it turns out to be a rather complicated approach. Then I say to the guy

*" That is somewhat complicated dude, let's keep it simple "*

Comment: You could just say "keep it simple".

Comment: @NathanReed Yes, but that could be misunderstood as a reduced form of KISS

Comment: Could you give a context for this? Otherwise, as the answers have shown, people give you options but you come up with other contextual things like--who are you saying this to? Teams? Individuals? Someone who knows the principle, or someone who doesn't?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this guy"? Does he know what KISS is, as this seems to be something of importance given your comments on answers?

Comment: @simchona The guy is not a friend of mine, but definitely knows about the KISS principle.

Comment: Much ado about nothing here, I think. "Keep it simple" is [ingrained into the lexicon](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+it+simple%2Ckeep+it+simple+stupid&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) enough that it wouldn't be construed to be insinuating the other person was 'stupid'. By itself, it's [used often enough](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=0517669153) in [inoffensive ways](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=1591285313).

Comment: Moreover, perhaps this is a generational thing, but, after examining your example, I think some people might be more inclined to be offended by the word "dude," than by the phrase "let's keep it simple" (although that would depend on the relationship between the parties talking, of course).

Comment: If the person who voted to reopen this question can explain why in a comment that would be helpful. I don't see any "improvement" or necessity why this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia lists several interesting [variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#Variants) to the "[KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)":

- "***Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication***" attributed to
  Leonardo da Vinci — sounds best to me.
- "keep it super simple"
- "keep it simple and straightforward"
- "keep it simple and sincere."
- "Less is more"

Comment: "Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication" is my new favorite, although "Less is more" applies the principle itself

Comment: I've also heard, Keep It Short & Simple, Or Face Frustration. (Ironically, although that phrase may be less "offensive," the resulting acronym is perhaps more so.)

Answer (score 5):

'Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.' (Attributed to Albert Einstein)

Comment: That's for sure, coming from someone that unified matter, energy and light in an equation with three variables.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing offensive about the KISS principle itself, despite the last S being humourously inserted in the acronym to make a full word.

Anyway, keeping it simple by saying "keep it simple" certainly isn't offensive, whether they know about the acronym or not.

Answer (score 3):

My father always used KISMIF: Keep It Simple; Make it Fun. That's not offensive. It seems to come from the [Cub Scouts](http://KISMIF.org/). I can remember it from that far back: pre: 1954.

Answer (score 3):

Two effective and succinct sayings in place of KISS:

> “If you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it
>   yourself.”  ― Albert Einstein
>
> "Simplicity is about subtracting the obvious and adding the
>   meaningful.”  ― John Maeda, The Laws of Simplicity: Design,
>   Technology, Business, Life

Answer (score 3):

I know it as "Keep It Short and Sweet". Hence, a kiss.

Comment: "keep it short n' simple" is my advice to English exam candidates.

Answer (score 2):

*Keep it simple stupid* doesn't seem offensive to me. But if you are concerned about the word *stupid*, you can be well off without it. So saying *let's keep it simple* will still get your point across.

Comment: "let's keep it simple" would get the point across without sounding offensive, "keep it simple" is kind of offensive if the other person know about the KISS principle

Comment: @rraallvv: I disagree with that; see my comment above. "Keep it simple" is used without the extra S-word [often enough](http://www.amazon.com/Keep-Simple-Busy-Women-Inspiring/dp/0736905537) that stupidity is unlikely to be implied.

Answer (score 1):

If you tell someone to KISS, then it can be offensive.

I would not be offended if you suggested that we applied the KISS principle to the issue...

Comment: It sounds good for team work, but how to suggest someone to apply the KISS principle on his own, if that person does know about the KISS principle